# Why does the Super Saiyan Transformation expose the Heart to Impurity?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the Dragon Ball Series, it is noted that the transformation exposes the heart to impurity, which is the reason Goku cannot use the spirit bomb offensively. (While in SSJ)
In the Movie Super Android 13, he uses Super Saiyan while charging the Spirit Bomb, but it exposes his heart to impurity and the energy is absorbed within him. (Which is what happens when a impure heart  attempts the spirit bomb), but why exactly does the Super Saiyan Transformation expose the heart to  impurity?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure if my answer is what you asking for, but Vegeta tells 19 that when they turn into super saiyan they tend to be more savage. For transforming for the first time you have to be very furious, and probably full of hatred. That might be why Super Saiyan expose the heart to impurity, since to be pure-hearted means to be a person with only good intentions

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Every time someone obtains a new SSJ form, their personality always darkens the first few times they use it. Goku SSJ1 barely could maintain his sanity against frieza, and in one dub yelled at Gohan to leave before he lost what little sense of reason he had left. Gohan SSJ2 turned from fighting hating to torturing Cell, and Goku SSJ3 clearly showed anger in his face when he used it against fat buu.

Comment: Pure hearted doesnt mean "good" intentions. As vegeta mentioned when he himself got SSJ he was pure hearted.....pure evil.